# Skipping Callout menu within context menu (ECB-Menu) in a list view of document library - SP2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, content-editor-web-part, script, ecb-menu

I would like to skip the preview-window (CallOut Menu) (red marked in my screenshot) within the context menu / ECB-Menu [(...)-Menu] of a document in a library **shown in any list view** and go straight into the menu (which is opened when clicking in the preview-window again on the (...).

[image]

I have a code solution for doing this when the document library is displayed standardly (not any list for navigating to document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-list-itemLink > a").each(function(){
        this.setAttribute("onclick","ShowECBMenuForTr(this.parentNode, event); return false;");
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I switch the view of document library to the view shown in my Screenshot, it doesn't work anymore. What do I have to add to this Code, that it also works for the view of document library shown in my Screenshot? (red marked with handmade "circles")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the new menu structure the easiest  way will be to modify the existing view or create a new view for that document library or list.

To do so perform the following steps:

- Go to your document library or list

  In the ribbon clock on Library and then either **Modify View or Create view**

[image]

- Once the view opens up you will scroll down to the bottom and you will see a section for **Styles** towards the bottom of the page on the left hand side. The current selection will be set to "Default"
  [image]

Select **Basic Table** view as this shows the items just as it looks in a default SharePoint 2007 document library and then **click OK to save the changes to the view**.

You will get this type of output:

[image]

## UPDATE

Please refer this link: http://www.booden.net/DirectAccessToEcb.aspx

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I have to stick to the existing view, because 90 % of asked Stakeholders want this as navigation tool through their documents. There are some Sites with document libraries, which have around 20 different types of documents and those lists include around 1000 documents. Therefore I can't just take the standard view as navigation tool. I really have to stick on just changing the code.

Comment: Please check. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your Update of the post was the part I was searching for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the three dots ... with the help of below CSS, event is attached to three dots.

```
.ms-list-itemLink  {display:none !important;}
```

Comment: your post is just a perfect addition to Dikesh's Link. Thanks for that